# How to subtract 2 values from different columns of the same row in the H2 database

Tags: sql, h2, subtraction

I'm trying to subtract 2 values from different columns of the same row in the H2 database.

[image: Database looks like this]:

**Data types:**

SLNO int, NUM1, NUM2 & OUTPUT are long
(have entered smaller numbers in this example for easier understanding).

**REQUIREMENT:**

I'm storing two long numbers under NUM1 & NUM2 columns.

I want to find out the difference between NUM2 - NUM1, the difference has to be stored under the column OUTPUT. I have gone through the documentation [H2 Database functions](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html) but did not find anything regarding this.

Could you please suggest alternative ways of doing this within the H2 database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to add [calculated column](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#computed_columns):

> A computed column is a column whose value is calculated before storing. The formula is evaluated when the row is inserted, and re-evaluated every time the row is updated.

```
CREATE TABLE SUBSTRACTION
(
  SLNO INT,
  NUM1 INT,
  NUM2 INT, 
  OUTPUT INT AS (NUM2 - NUM1)
);
```

This will guarantee that `OUTPUT` will be always up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

try `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE substraction
SET OUTPUT = NUM2 - NUM1
```

Comment: This needs an explanation to be useful for both the OP and longevity.